# Apache is giving 500 instead of 408 if tomcat dosen't respond within timeout period of apache

Tags: apache, rest, tomcat

we have set up with Apache and tomcat with another third party data storage server. We support API call through which one can upload a file and in turn tomcat stores that file on third party data storage server.

Timeout for that API request now is 10 hours and Apache request timeout is 2 Minutes. However tomcat sometimes takes more then 2 minutes to upload that file. And in the mean time Apache sends 500 internal server error instead of 408 request timeout error. In the whole process tomcat successfully uploads that file but client who has made API call will get 500 error with understanding that file is not uploaded so again it will try to upload making it a duplicate entry.

we are using apache proxy ajp. Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know that error. As of Apache 2.4.40, it cannot send 500, it either send a gateway read timeout or bad gateway. The 408 will be send by apache if YOUR client fails to deliver timely. You have to know how long the longest request will take on the Tomcat and change `ProxyTimeout` accordingly. I did and it solved my issue.